# Using condition "true or false" into range in helm chart

Tags: helm3

I had deployed a helm chart but I got stuck with a range use condition.
In deployment.yml

```
{{ range $component_key, $component := .Values.components }}
{{ if or $.Values.deploy_with_hub_nas (eq $component.deploy_redis.enable "true") }}
name: {{ $component.name }}
{{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

In value.yml

```
deploy_with_hub_nas: false # Set to "true" if you want to freshly deploy all components.
components:
  redis:
    deploy_redis:
      enable: true
    name: redis
    image: redis
    ports:
      - port: 6379
  rabbitmq:
    deploy_rabbitmq: false # Set to "True" if you want to deploy RabbitMQ, or set to "False" if You've got RabbitMQ.
    name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - port: 5672
```

I wanna deploy only Redis, so I set deploy_redis.enable = true but I got an error message.

```
  executing "./deployment.yaml" at <$component.deploy_redis.enable>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.enable
```

How can I fix it if I use range?

If I remove the range and use `.Values.deploy_redis.enable` it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from the second block of the code:

```
  rabbitmq:
    deploy_rabbitmq: false # Set to "True" if you want to deploy RabbitMQ, or set to "False" if You've got RabbitMQ.
    name: rabbitmq
    image: rabbitmq
    ports:
      - port: 5672
```

When the range tries to find `deploy_redis` for the `rabbitmq` key, it throws the error.

I would either make all of your keys have the same fields, or add another conditional to check if the current key is `redis`.